# Unable to connect Solix application to archive database progress

Tags: openedge, progress-db

Progress version:- 9.1d

OS version:- HP-UX hkiad1 B.11.31 U ia64 3563221874 unlimited-user license

There is an application Solix that is use archiving database from db trying to connect but throwing error. To connect I did below steps:

1: - I login with root user that we usually do mpro dbname and go to admin and security and create a user database and give password.

2: - I started secondary broker like :- $DLC/bin/_mprosrv /db1/dbtest/pring -m3 -S pring-l -ServerType SQL

3: - given a port in /etc/services file with pring-l 4003/tcp

4: - I have given to the Solix team, but they are getting error:- below

Unable to connect to specified database. Please verify detail.

Solix detail they are entering:

Source : pring

Name:-Source

Connection type:- JDBC

Instance name pring

Database password: db password that i create db level user.

target

Database: progress version 9.x

IP address od server: Ip address

Database user: test ( that i create db level in mpro db name > data dictionary > security> add user and password

Database Port Number:

Comment: Please show the actual error message.

Comment: I see in DB log file :- 23:21:00 BROKER 1: SQL server process terminated. (8841) 23:32:16 BROKER 1: SQL server process terminated. (8841)

Comment: Hi Tom , if I do as you suggested,showing me below:- Inserting /progress9/dlc/bin to beginning of path and the current directory is /progress9/wrk. PROGRESS Version 9.1D05 as of Mon Feb 3 12:12:52 EST 2003 proenv>sqlexp -user test -password test -db /db1/dbtest/pring -S pring-l PROGRESS Version 9.1D05 as of Mon Feb 3 12:12:52 EST 2003 Connecting user "test" to URL "jdbc:jdbcprogress:T:localhost:singapor-l:pring"... (8920) null proenv>

Answer (score 0):

If you have successfully started the db with the SQL server as described then you should see a message to that effect in the database log file. Some mixture of messages along these lines:

```
(5644)  Started for 9110 using TCP IPV4 address 0.0.0.0, pid 122817.
(452)   Login by tom on /dev/pts/1.
(5644)  Started for 9210 using TCP IPV4 address 0.0.0.0, pid 122833.
(19552) Broker with server num 2 logged in.
(5645)  This is an additional broker for this protocol.
(4259)  Minimum Clients Per Server (-Mi): 1
(4257)  Maximum Number of Clients Per Server (-Ma): 10
(12819) Servers per Protocol (-Mp): 0
(5647)  Maximum Servers Per Broker (-Mpb): 5
(5648)  Minimum Port for Auto Servers (-minport): 11000
(5649)  Maximum Port for Auto Servers (-maxport): 11999
(8864)  This broker supports SQL server groups only.
```

You should also be able to verify that you can make a SQL connection to that server with the local sqlexp command. Something similar to this:

```
sqlexp  -user userName -password passWord -db dbName -S servicePort
```

If you can make that local connection then you have properly setup the server side of things and the issue is with the configuration of client trying to connect or the network in between.

Comment: Hi Tom , 

if I do as you suggested,showing me below:-

 
Inserting /progress9/dlc/bin to beginning of path and

the current directory is /progress9/wrk.

PROGRESS Version 9.1D05 as of Mon Feb  3 12:12:52 EST 2003

proenv>sqlexp -user test -password test -db /db1/dbtest/pring -S  pring-l

PROGRESS Version 9.1D05 as of Mon Feb  3 12:12:52 EST 2003

Connecting user "test" to URL "jdbc:jdbcprogress:T:localhost:singapor-l:pring"... (8920)
null
proenv>

Comment: I see in DB log file :- 23:21:00 BROKER  1: SQL server process terminated. (8841)
23:32:16 BROKER  1: SQL server process terminated. (8841)

Comment: Does it means that JDBC driver not installed?

Comment: No, it means that you have not successfully started the SQL broker for unknown reasons. Extended back and forth debugging discussions are not really suitable for stackoverflow.